# Unable to add an EXE file as a reference to a project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I am trying to add an `.exe` file '[Hearthstonedecktracker.exe](https://hsreplay.net/downloads/)' to a plugin that I cloned into Visual Studio 2022. I can find the exe just fine but I get the following error:

[image]

> Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component

I've made sure that the file is accessible, and according to the [documentation](https://github.com/HearthSim/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker/wiki/FAQ), the exe should be able to be added as a reference to C# projects, so I'm confused why I'm getting this error and if there's anything that can be done to fix it.

My only thought is that maybe  it's because its in a different hard drive than the exe, but I don't think that should matter. Otherwise I haven't been able to find any documentation on what to do in this scenario, because I need to implement classes from this exe in my project.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to add a reference or a resource? It appears to be a reference but you say "resource" in your question, so please edit that to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you can only reference DLLs, not EXEs. If it is a .NET application, you may be able to simply rename the file and change the extension in order to reference it. Also, you need to make sure that the framework is compatible to that which your project is targeting, e.g. you can't reference assemblies targeting .NET Framework in a .NET Core project.

Comment: Are you sure you want to reference it anyway? Are you trying to access the types and members defined in that assembly directly in your code, or are you trying to interact with the EXE from the outside, or something else?

Comment: @jmcilhinney It should work fine to add an exe as a reference. But it has to be a .Net exe (or COM). So the most likely explanation is that the file is not, in fact, a .Net assembly, exactly as the error message says. Open the file in something like ILSpy to confirm.

Comment: Fixed the post, thanks for pointing that out. I'm kinda at step 0 right now. I'm loosely following 2 tutorials for working with the exe, both of which add HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe as a reference. 

when I cloned in one of the repos It was using .net 4.5 instead of the recommended 4.8 I believe, I tried with both versions and both yielded the same error.

The HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe is created via running the installer for [this repo](https://github.com/HearthSim/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker), can i add it as a reference directly or something?

Comment: Did you create a .NET 4.7.2 project for your new plugin? If not, if you tried to create a .NET 7 library for instance, then this would explain the issue. You have to match the .NET verion/framework.

Comment: You seem to be having the same issue, you need to reference the application which is the exe file in the folder, please refer to https://github.com/HearthSim/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker/issues/3635

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT "You need to reference the exe file in an app folder: %LOCALAPPDATA%\HearthstoneDeckTracker\app-1.6.3\HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe" this fixed the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JonnyCross Hi, I am glad that you can solve this issue. I will post the comment as an answer. You can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to should not be the assembly generated by .net but the C++ launcher/updater exe generated by Squirrel. This cannot be added to the Reference of a .net project.

What you need to reference is %LOCALAPPDATA%\HearthstoneDeckTracker\app-1.6.3\HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe.

Reference from: https://github.com/HearthSim/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker/issues/3635